# urlencode send form

Tags: html, forms, urlencode

I have a simple search form

```
<form id="search" name="search" method="GET" action="search.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

But this form doesn't encode all chars in a URL, `'` isn't encoded to `%27`, shouldn't this be done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather funny.. On the HTML specification it states that all Non-alphanumeric characters are represented by %HH (according to RFC 1738, Section 2.2). But if you actually go to the RFC1738, Section 2.2 has the following:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special
>   characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their
>   reserved purposes may be used
>   **unencoded** within a URL.

But Chrome seems to follow the specification to the letter, where as IE and Firefox choose to not encode those characters..